# Restricting additional Downloads

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have some items in recyclerview, loaded from a server...
i managed to set onClicks in the item & then show a Dialog...
I gave some conditions for dialog...

```
    if(isDownloading()){
//Dialog shows Cancel Download button
}

    else if(isDownloaded()){
//Dialog shows Delete Button...
}

else{
//Dialog shows Download Button 
}
```

my problem is that I want to allow only One Download at a time...
if the user selects another item then how can i show a dialog sayin like "Download Pendin, try later"

Any Help will be appreciated :)

Comment: do you already have logic to check if anything is downloading ?? or your problem is to only avoid multiple downloads at same time ??

Comment: @OmarDanisha Yes, I have a method which shows if a file is downloading... just want to restrict other downloads

Comment: `Download Pendin, try later` that's lame approach. Use queue

Comment: Keep a boolean somewhere `isDownloadInProgress` and update it at download start and end. But I agree with @MarcinOrlowski, try to implement a Queue and start the next one when one finishes.

Answer (score 0):

maybe not best approach , you can use `sharedpreferences` ,

```
    checkdownload();
    int v = pref.getInt("key_name", 3)
        if(v==1){
        //download
        }else{
        // show download is pending
        }
```

as you told you already have method to check status ....

```
public void checkdownload(){
    ....
    ....
    if(pending){
    editor.putInt("key_name", 0)
    editor.commit();
    }else{
       editor.putInt("key_name", 1)
     editor.commit();
       }
    }
```